# css keyframe animations starting position changing

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have a deck of cards and the cards have this rule:

```
@-webkit-keyframes playersCardMove {
  from {left: -180px; bottom: 157px;}
}
```

this animation shows the card moving from the deck to the players hand. however, the problem is that once the second card is drawn, it is drawn from a different starting position because it is relative to where it's going to get placed.

how can I place all cards horizontally next to each other whilst ensuring that the starting position is always the same?

code:

```
.card{
  width: 90px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
  animation: cardMove 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.playersCard{
  animation: playersCardMove 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


  {playersHand.map((card) => {
        return <div className="playersCard card">
          <div>{card.rank.rank}</div>
          <div className="imageContainer">
            <img className="cardImage" src={card.image} />
          </div>
          <div>{card.suit}</div>
        </div>
      })}
```

Comment: starting point is always the same == don't specify from, but only specify to

Comment: @TemaniAfif but then I don't seem to get a smooth transition...and it still is starting them from different points?

Comment: share your full code then so we can better see

Comment: @TemaniAfif would it be easier for me to point you to the github repo and specific files so you can take a better look?

Comment: if it was private yes, but since you are asking here you should share a running code to the community so we can help you ... the question should include the behavior and not link to an external links.

Comment: I agree @TemaniAfif but I just think I'm going to be posting lots of code. but I'll see what I can do

Comment: @TemaniAfif does that help?

Comment: no really as we need to have working code .. you may try using https://jsfiddle.net/ or codepen to put your code

Comment: ok set up a fiddle and now it's not working at all :/ https://jsfiddle.net/ppvx65nk/4/

Comment: ok, now it's moving kinda...

Comment: @TemaniAfif https://codesandbox.io/s/mq12q60z09, this is kinda working but I want it to go from the same place and then placed on the right to the previous one if that makes sense